# How to return nested array from wasm_bindgen function

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I have a rust program which I would like to run as web assembly in javascript. I have a function which I want to return a 3D array, so I can plot some data on a graph on the frontend, but I cannot find a way to return such data. Having a look at js_sys there is no general Array type, only specific types for 2D arrays such as Uint32Array.

I would like the function signature to look something like this:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn sk_dataset(input: &str) -> Vec<Vec<i32>>;
```

I have tried return a struct with the wasm_bindgen decorator like this:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct DataSet {

    pub data: Vec<Vec<i32>>
}
```

But I get an error stating that

```
the trait bound `Vec<i32>: JsObject` is not satisfied
required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoWasmAbi` for `Box<[Vec<i32>]>`
```

The tutorial over at https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/exported-rust-types.html only has examples of structs exported with basic types like i32s, how can I export a struct with more complex members?

Comment: Looks like I neglected to read the page on Serde, which enables you to serialise arbitrary types: https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/arbitrary-data-with-serde.html

Comment: Just a word of warning, serialization and deserialization will be fairly slow, especially if the `Vec`s are large. I don't know enough about wasm bindgen to recommend a better solution though.

Comment: your question sounds similar to that example of wasm where an menory buffer ist returned from Rust to JS.
may be that approach is a better fit.
https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/implementing.html